# Embeding a PDF and having it searchable in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, search, pdf

I have a 32 page 6 megabyte pdf that i would like to embed for viewing on my wordpress site. However I need the text in it to be searchable by the wordpress search bar (i am willing to edit the search functions to do this) I tried converting the pdf to html but had no success. Any scripts, hacks, or  plugins would help. Im open to any and all sugestions.

Answer (score 0):

Google can index the content of PDF files, though I'm not sure if Bing can. What I suggest that you do, considering that you don't want to convert your PDF files to HTML then post it on your site, is to change from the built in Wordpress Search, and instead use the Google Search Plugin.

You can use the Google Custom Search [widget](http://www.google.com/cse/tools/create_onthefly), or use the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/).

Maybe [Ligit](http://www.lijit.com/) might help, provided that they use Google to search your site.

Comment: whould that allow the verbal content of the pdf to be searchable also because that is my goal

Comment: Google indexes the content of PDF files, so as long as your PDF files are indexed by Google, then yes.